# Constructor for class 'QSharedPointer<T>' is declared 'explicit' - How to resolve this error

Tags: qt, qsharedpointer

I get the following error when trying to use:

```
typedef QSharedPointer<Test> CTest


CTest* Module::function(params)
{
    CTestNew* ptr = new CTestNew(params);

    dosomething();

    return ptr;
}
```

Then replace Test* with CTest in the code. 
What am I missing?

```
error C2664: 'QSharedPointer<T>::QSharedPointer(const QSharedPointer<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CTestNew*' to 'const QSharedPointer<T> &'
            with
            [
               T=Test
            ]
            Reason: cannot convert from 'CTestNew *' to 'const QSharedPointer<T>'
            with
            [
                T=Test
           ]
            Constructor for class 'QSharedPointer<T>' is declared 'explicit'
            with
            [
                T=Test
            ]
```

Comment: you should provide a more clear title for your question to get better answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler error's saying that `CTestNew` isn't the same as `Test`

EDIT: In response to comments saying `CTestNew` is a subclass of the abstract `Test`

```
CTest* Module::function(params)
{
    CTestNew* ptr = new CTestNew(params);
    dosomething();
    return ptr;
}
```

should be:

```
CTest Module::function(params) // Don't return a pointer to a shared pointer
{
    Test * ptr = new Test(params); // You're using Test not CTestNew in the CTest typedef
    dosomething();
    return CTest(static_cast<Test *>(ptr));
}
```

Comment: Don't use `CTestNew` where you need to use `Test`.

Comment: @Ronny: He's doing `CTest foo(new CTestNew)` or something similar, where he should do `CTest foo(new Test)` - At least that's what the compiler error claims.

Comment: I see. In this case you'd be right. He needs to clarify this.

Comment: @Rony/Erik: Thanks for your comments. There is a function Test* function(parameters) in which a pointer to CTestNew is created. CTestNew * ptr= dosomething() and this function returns  CTestNew. It worked prior to me adding the typedef because CTestNew is inherited from Test. Should I do a typecast in this case?

Comment: CTest* Module::function(params)
{
 CTestNew* ptr = new CTestNew(params);

 dosomething();
 
 return ptr;
}

Comment: @VIJ: use `CTest Module::function(params) { Test * ptr = new Test; ... return ptr; }`

Comment: Thanks. I cannot instantiate Test because it is an abstract class. I use the return type CTest . Also, CTestNew inherits from Test. CTestNew:public Test .Should I use casting?

Comment: In that case you need to `return CTest(static_cast<Test *>(ptr));`

Comment: When I use a 'go to definition' or F12 in my CTestNew which is the newly introduced typedef, I get an error 'symbol not defined'.However, it is not the case with other parts of the code.I have done a clean rebuild.What could be the reason?

Comment: @VIJ: No idea - that's a completely different question, you should post a new one.